# My Boyer-Moore algorithm only searches the first 3000ish characters in my text file

Tags: c++, text-files, boyer-moore

I'm trying to implement a Boyer-Moore string search algorithm. The search algorithm itself seems to work fine, up until a point. It prints out all occurrences until it reaches around the 3300 character area, then it does not search any further.
I am unsure if this is to do with the text file being too big to fit into my string or something entirely different. When I try and print the string holding the text file, it cuts off the first 185122 characters as well. For reference, the text file is Lord of the Rings: Fellowship of the Ring - it is 1016844 characters long.
Here is my code for reference:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
# define number_chars 256
typedef std::chrono::steady_clock clocktime;

void boyer_moore(string text, string pattern, int textlength, int patlength) {
    clocktime::time_point start = clocktime::now();
    vector<int> indexes;
    int chars[number_chars];
    for (int i = 0; i < number_chars; i++) {
        chars[i] = -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < patlength; i++) {
        chars[(int)pattern[i]] = i;
    }
    int shift = 0;
    while (shift <= (textlength - patlength)) {
        int j = patlength - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && pattern[j] == text[shift + j]) {
            j--;
        }
        if (j < 0) {
            indexes.push_back(shift);
            if (shift + patlength < textlength) {
                shift += patlength - chars[text[shift + patlength]];
            }
            else {
                shift += 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            shift += max(1, j - chars[text[shift + j]]);
        }
    }
    clocktime::time_point end = clocktime::now();
    auto time_taken = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    for (int in : indexes) {
        cout << in << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    ifstream myFile;
    //https://www.kaggle.com/ashishsinhaiitr/lord-of-the-rings-text/version/1#01%20-%20The%20Fellowship%20Of%20The%20Ring.txt
    myFile.open("lotr.txt");
    if (!myFile) {
        cout << "no text file found";
    }
    string text((istreambuf_iterator<char>(myFile)), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    cout << text;
    string pattern;
    cin >> pattern;
    int n = text.size();
    int m = pattern.size();
    boyer_moore(text, pattern, n, m);
}
```

I have tried to do some researching about what could be the cause but couldn't find anyone with this particular issue. Would appreciate any nudges in the right direction.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger, paying attention in particular to the value of `shift`?

Comment: @Shawn I have taken a look now - I notice that the value of shift right before the function ends is some obscenely large number but I am unsure why, 85899651516 to be exact. Could this be to do with ASCII vs Unicode?

Comment: I'd be inclined as a first guess to suspect it being set to some random value like that because of an out of bounds array access. Running through `valgrind` or compiling with `-fsanitize=address` would be a good next step.